# How to convert between BSON and JSON, especially for those special objects?

Tags: json, mongodb, bson

I am **not** asking for any libraries to do so and I am just writing code for `bson_to_json` and `json_to_bson`.

so here is the [BSON specification](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification).

For regular double, doc, array, string, it is fine and it is easy to convert between BSON and JSON.

However, for those particular objects, such as

**`Timestamp` and `UTC`**:

If convert from JSON to BSON, how can I know they are timestamp and utc?

**`Regex` (string, string), `JavaScript code with scope` (string, doc)**

their structures have multiple parts, how can I present the structures in JSON?

**`Binary data` (generic, function, etc)`**

How can I present the type of binary data in JSON?

**`int32` and `int64`**

How can I present them in JSON, so BSON can know which is 32 bit or 64 bit?

Thanks

Comment: JSON cannot express these objects so it a case of getting gthe string/int representation. You will need to decide whether you want a int timestamp or a string ISODate back from your conversion functions. And you cannot know the difference between 32bit and 64bit number once they reach JSON other than a number being greater than 2147483647 really. Also are you ever going to be using `Timestamp`? It is a internal object and shouldn't be used externally by the user, you should only ever be dealing with `ISODate()`

Comment: oh, ok, For `timestamp`, I should remove the api I guess.

Comment: @Sammaye Are there any other fields I should allow user to create?

Comment: Javascript might be a troubling one, that should only be used for system.js function storage. So you might wanna not allow that. For converting a Regex you could use the PCRE format of `/your_first_string/you_second_string_of_modifiers` to represent that in JSON. Binary data should have its data property encoded to base 64 and inserted as string.

Comment: @Sammaye thanks for your suggestions, I guess you could convert all your comments to answer

Comment: If you tell me which driver this is I might be able to place an exact answer since the driver of a specific language will actually translate the field types to objects within the native environment

Comment: @Sammaye Actually I am writing a ocaml driver for Mongodb.

Comment: Ah you decided to go through with that? Ok you will, once you decode the BSON, get fields in their serialised edition, so, i.e. ObjectId will be `{'$id': "hex_string_of_id"}` and date will be `{'$sec':567676,'$usec':5667676}` you will need to output the buffer to find out exactly how you get them back but from there you will need to reach in and rip out their contents, i.e. to output the date you will need to most likely access the `$sec` property and use that to build either a Timestamp or a string ISODate, most drivers deserialise it into their native language date object.

Comment: In addition these are the types used in PHP for example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.types.php it seems that they have made a deseraliser for Timestamp, though they mention it is only really useful if you wanna make sharding tools so depite that you might be able to leave it out

Comment: @Sammaye Thanks. For the ocaml mongodb driver, actually I am not thinking of writing a real production level one, I just want to sharpen my ocaml skills and I am a fan of MongoDB, that's why. could you please summarize your comments to answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know JSON cannot express objects so you will need to decide how you want the stringified version of the BSON objects (field types) to be represented within the output of your ocaml driver.

Some of the data types are easy, `Timestamp` is not needed since it is internal to sharding only and `Javascript` blocks are best left out due to the fact that they are best used only within `system.js` as saved functions for use in MRs.

You also gotta consider that some of these fields are actually both in and out. What I mean by in and out is that some are used to specify input documents to be serialised to BSON and some are part of output document that need deserialising from BSON into JSON.

`Regex` is one which will most likely be a field type you send down. As such you will need to serialise your ocaml object to the BSON equivilant of `{$regex: 'd', '$options': 'ig'}` from `/d/ig` PCRE representation.

`Date`s can be represented in JSON by either choosing to use the ISODate string or a timestamp for the representation. The output will be something like `{$sec:556675,$usec:6787}` and you can convert `$sec` to the display you need.

`Binary` data in JSON can be represented by taking the `data` (if I remember right) property from the output document and then encoding that to base 64 and storing it as a stirng in the field.

`int32` and `int64` has no real definition between the two in JSON except that 64bit ints will be bigger than 2147483647 so I am unsure if you can keep the data types unique there.

That should help get you started.